# How does one check what version of Oracle ODAC or Oracle Client library download include oracle.dataaccess.dll v4.121.2.0

Tags: oracle, installation

Is there a way to check either the Oracle ODAC or the Oracle Client library download (or instructions) to see if it includes `oracle.dataaccess.dll  v4.121.2.0`, before installation? For example, in release notes etc.

Answer (score 0):

All components and version are declared at Oracle Download page, e.g. [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)

> **64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) Xcopy for Windows x64
>   [Released October 5, 2015]**
>
> Download Includes
>
> 64-bit Oracle Data Provider for .NET 4 12.1.0.2.0
>
> 64-bit Oracle Data Provider for .NET 2.0 12.1.0.2.0
>
> 64-bit Oracle Providers for ASP.NET 4 12.1.0.2.0
>
> 64-bit Oracle Providers for ASP.NET 2.0 12.1.0.2.0
>
> 64-bit Oracle Provider for OLE DB 12.1.0.2.0
>
> 64-bit Oracle Services for Microsoft Transaction Server 12.1.0.2.0
>
> 64-bit Oracle Instant Client 12.1.0.2.0